# What's wrong with this angular js code ( I am using this instead of scope in controllers)

Tags: angularjs

Can you please tell me what's wrong with this code. It works fine when I use $scope but not when I replace it with the following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as person">

`<h1>{{person.name}}</h1>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function() {
    var student = {name:"Volvo",
                   age: 20};
     this.student = student;



});
</script>

<p>The property "carname" was made in the controller, and can be referred to in the view by using the {{ }} brackets.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here person is alias for myCtrl.

Su use like, `person.student.name`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<h1>{{person.student.name}}</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you defined the scope nor reference to pull that data, whether pulled straight from your model or from some sort of API. Are you missing showing something here?